# Convert DateTimeOffset to User's local time?

Tags: datetime, datetimeoffset

If my server time is 4/29/2016 11:00PM and the user's current time is 4/30/2016 5:00AM.  How can I convert the Server Time represented as a DateTimeOffset into the user's time?

I used the above user time as an example, but I will need to be able convert the server time to any user local time?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ToLocalTime()`. [documentation here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset.tolocaltime(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Doesn't this convert the time to server local time?  Not the user's local time?